# Adding points with coordinates from CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, csv, import

I want to add to my vector file layers with some points to show animals occurrences in Germany for different years.

I have all the coordinates in a CSV file (see image attached) but when I want to charge it on QGIS (add layer "Data source manager/delimiter text") I actually can't.

[image: Data Source Manger, delimited text]

[image]

[image]

Comment: change it to **custom delimiter** and set it to  **";"** right now it tries to create breaks between columns with a **","** which results in a single column with the name "Species;Long (x); Lat (y)".

Comment: From your image, it seems QGIS fails to differenciate the fields (see "Y field" and "Y field"). Try telling it your separator is semi-colons and not commas. On another note, I am not 100% your field names can inclue spaces and brackets. I would avoid them.

Comment: The coordinates of EPSG:3035 are not decimal degrees but meters (northing/easting).  If your coordinates are decimal degrees, then the CRS is not EPSG:3035

Comment: Thank you to all of you, I could charge my layer, however, my points do not appear on top of my already existing layers... (i.e. I want to see my species occurrences on the area I am looking at which is projected with CSR 30:35), do you know why?  I added a screen capture for more details

Comment: As mentioned by @nmtoken your coordinates are expressed in decimal degrees. If I project your points using WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326), they are in Germany. Wolves in the East, seals on the coast or in the sea. You can later reproject your points to the desired CRS.

Comment: Hi Chloe, thanks for your reply, I added a screen capture of what happened when I project my coordinates with CSR 4326...  how can i make sure it fits the CSR of the project (I.e. 3035)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I copied the first 7 points from your table in an Excel file. The first thing I did was setting the fields as numeric with 8 decimals (this [avoids issues in ArcGIS](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018076), but I don't know if it is necessary in QGIS). I saved this file as a CSV:

```
Species;X;Y
Canis Lupus;14.68940700;51.39577900
Canis Lupus;14.83051300;51.39577900
Grey seal;7.91667900;54.18514300
Grey seal;7.91667900;54.18514300
Grey seal;8.57837500;53.55751300
Grey seal;7.88759200;54.15673600
Grey seal;8.58589800;53.54853900
```

Then I used the "Create points layer from table" tool from QGIS. As your coordinate values seemed to be in decimal degrees, I used the default WGS 84 (EPSG: 2436):
[image: Screen capture of the tool settings and result]

To reproject your data in the desired CRS, you can follow this [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs).

Answer (score 1):

I started by charging my csv file to add delimited text layer, I made sure to set it to ";" and I used the CRS WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) despite the fact than my project is in 3035....
I can see my points on the map :)

Comment: If you want to understand more about why your data can be visualised despite the CRS being different to the project, you can [read here about "on-the-fly" transformation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#:~:text=QGIS%20supports%20%E2%80%9Con,to%20each%20other!).

Comment: Thank you a lot!